# Image in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, image

I have been playing around a lot with this the past few weeks, but now I am getting desperate. I have a very simple GridView in my default.aspx which display images from a folder based on the server.

I display them in the gridivew and i put the width and height to 300px; So it creates a square of 300 by 300 pixels like it should be.

But this makes the images crop to 300x300 pixels, but I want the pictures at their original size with a overflow:hidden;

I tried to add it trough css on the imagefield, but nothing is happening.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ShowHeader="False"
>
<Columns>

    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="value">
        <ControlStyle CssClass="test" Height="300px" Width="300px" />
        <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
        <ItemStyle Height="300px" Width="300px" />
    </asp:ImageField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CSS**

```
 .test{
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: You can check that "test" css has been aplied to image or not? you can also use template field to display images in gridview

Comment: Yes I just added a 10px padding with bluebackground. Def working

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

How about change img to div, and use image as background:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ShowHeader="False"
>
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="background-image:url(<%# Eval("value") %>);width:300px;height:300px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```